# Why const double && doesn't work for lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

Explain me, please, how it works?
Why double && works for lvalue and rvalue?
And why const double && don't work for lvalue?

```
template <typename U>
void function(U& var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int var1 = 45;
    function(var1);
    function(45); //error
}
```

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’ function(45);
////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
template <typename U>
void function(const U& var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int var1 = 45;
    function(var1);
    function(45);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
template <typename U>
void function(U&& var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int var1 = 45;
    function(var1);
    function(45);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
template <typename U>
void function(const U&& var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int var1 = 45;
    function(var1);  // error
    function(45);
}
```

error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘const int&&’ function(var1);

Comment: Please include any error messages in your question.

Comment: I believe *all* answers on the right side "Related" section can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double &&` does not work for lvalues. However, you don't have `double &&` in your code, you have `U &&` for a deduced `U`. That is special syntax for a so-called *forwarding reference.*

There's a special rule in C++ template deduction rules which says that when the parameter type is `T&&` where `T` is a deduced type, and the argument is an lvalue of type `X`, then `X&` is used instead of `X` for type deduction.

In your case, this means `U` is deduced to be `int&`, so the type of parameter `var` is collapsed from "`int& &&`" into `int &`.

You can learn more about this mechanism by searching for terms such as "forwarding reference" (historically called "universal reference") or "perfect forwarding."

Answer (score 2):

Let's summarize the rules at first.

1. lvalues can be bound to lvalue-reference
2. lvalues can't be bound to rvalue-reference
3. rvalues can be bound to lvalue-reference to const
4. rvalues can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const
5. rvalues can be bound to rvalue-reference
6. lvalues can be bound to forwarding-reference (and preserve its value category)
7. rvalues can be bound to forwarding-reference (and preserve its value category)

The 1st case is lvalue-reference to non-const, then

```
function(var1); // rule#1 -> fine
function(45);   // rule#4 -> fail
```

the 2nd case is lvalue-reference to const, then

```
function(var1); // rule#1 -> fine
function(45);   // rule#3 -> fine
```

the 3rd case is forwarding-reference, then

```
function(var1); // rule#6 -> fine
function(45);   // rule#7 -> fine
```

the 4th case is rvalue-reference, then

```
function(var1); // rule#2 -> fail
function(45);   // rule#5 -> fine
```

It's worth noting the difference between rvalue-reference and [forwarding-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references):

(emphasis mine)

> function parameter of a function template declared as rvalue reference to cv-**unqualified** type template parameter of that same function template

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `function(var1)` is going to deduce `var1` usage as `lvalue`. To make it compatible with rvalue-based template, you have to help your compiler a bit:

```
template <typename U>
void function(const U&& var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int var1 = 45;
    function(std::move(var1));  // let convert lvalue to rvalue
    function(45);
}
```

P.S. And yes, you should always ask yourself "do I really need that rvalue reference, or I'm perfectly fine with that old good lvalue ref?"